# Logic error "Undefined or garbage value returned to caller"

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is wrong with the following statements?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *title;

    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            title = @"Section 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = @"Section 2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return title;
}
```

Why do I get the logic error "Undefined or garbage value returned to caller" on analyzing this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set NSString * title to nil: `NSString * title = nil;`
 if(section is neither 0 nor 1 ) then switch (section) goes through default: and then it return title; which is just pointer pointing to nothing or uninitialized. 
So assign title string to nil; where you declared it.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *title = nil;

    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            title = @"Section 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = @"Section 2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return title;
}
```

Comment: This also applies to heightForRowAtIndexPath when setting and returning an int.  So "int cellHeight;" would need to be "int cellHeight = 0;" similar to what is happening with this NSString.

Answer (score 2):

Because when `section` isn't `1` or `2`, `title` is uninitialized. You can either initialize it in the first line or in the `default` case of the `switch` statement.